# For loop does not work in p5js and I dont know why

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2)
  let amount = 12;
  for (let a = 0; a < amount; a += (360 / amount)) {
    xm = cos(a) * 100;
    ym = sin(a) * 100;
    strokeWeight(4);
    fill(255);
    ellipse(xm, ym, 10);
    console.log(a)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I try to make 12 points on a circle ( This will be a watch face). I don't know why this is not working please help me.

Comment: `a < amount` you maybe meant `a < 360`

Comment: Yup, looks like just a typo. You will also want `angleMode(DEGREES)` in your `setup()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `angleMode(DEGREES)` so you can use degrees instead of radians (more info here: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/angleMode)
Also you want to go from 0 to 360 instead of to 12 (amount) I created a var to hold the 360 to avoid confusion. There you go!

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  let totalCircle = 360;
  background(220);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2)
  let amount = 12;
  for (let a = 0; a < totalCircle; a += (totalCircle / amount)) {
    xm = cos(a) * 100;
    ym = sin(a) * 100;
    strokeWeight(4);
    fill(255);
    ellipse(xm, ym, 10);
    console.log(a)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```